# My computer shuts down exactly after 2 hrs

Tags: desktop-computer

My desktop pc with windows 10 shuts down after 2 hours. I have reinstall the windows, clean the cpu and gpu fans. But still problem is same. Please help me to resolve my pc issue.

Comment: Any scheduled tasks configured?

Comment: No nothing. No scheduled task

Comment: Please try to add details about your system: PSU, Motherboard, etc. Also: Does it shutdown abruptly without warning, or does it show you "Shutting Down Windows" and then shuts off?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-automatic-restart-system-failure-windows) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

To find the reason why your computer shutdowns, go to start, type Event Viewer and press enter.

In the left pane of Event Viewer, double click/tap on Windows Logs to expand it, click on System to select it, then right click on System, and click/tap on Filter Current Log.

In the field, type 1074, then click/tap on OK

This will give you a list of power off (shutdown) and restart Shutdown Type of events at the top of the middle pane in Event Viewer.

You can scroll through these listed events to find the events with power off as the Shutdown Type. You will notice the date and time, and what user was responsible for shutting down the computer per power off event listed.

You may also remove the filter and check items nearby 1074 events to find related messages.

Comment: Getting the first 50 reputation on stack overflow is really hard.

Comment: you're twice as far along as you were before. Volunteering to edit questions will also aid your progress.

Comment: It showing the error "intel management engine interface driver has failed to perform handshake with firmware

Comment: That is a driver issue but I dont see a clear correlation there. Have you found any 1074 events corresponding to unexpected shutdowns?

Comment: In this event id only shows that event when I restarted or shutdown event. But it does not show the events when pc shutdown by itself. Pls help to resolve